# How do I prohibit access to a file type except for a few files

Tags: iis, request-filtering

Is there a way to configure IIS to prohibit serving a certain type of files, but still allow it for a specific number of files? I need to disallow access to .property files, but there are a few of them that still need to be served. I can prohibit a specific file type with Request Filtering feature, or simply remove .properties extension from the list of MIME types. But how do I make an exception for a specific file path, or folder?

Ideally, I wouldn't want to move the files to another place or change their original extension to something else (so that it doesn't match the actual content).

Comment: You'd better use URL Rewrite module and create several rules if needed.

Comment: @LexLi I hoped there was a simple configuration change that I just overlooked. Too bad I need to resort to URL Rewrite, but I have no other choice. This sounds like an answer to me.